# phantom file in directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, directory

There seems to be a phantom file in my directory that I can't get rid of.

If I run the following then the following filename is printed out:

```
$ for i in *.xml; do echo $i; done
...
gerhardloci.xml
...
```

If run `ls -la` I get a missing file error followed by a list of files that are actually in the directory--and `gerhardloci.xml` is one of them.

```
$ ls -la
ls: ./gerhardloci.xml: No such file or directory
<file list>
```

Likewise if I start typing `cat gerha` and then hit tab, bash will complete the file name, as if recognizing that the file `gerhardloci.xml` is in the directory.

And yet if try to remove it I get an error:

```
$ rm gerhardloci.xml
rm: can't remove 'gerhardloci.xml': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Try `ls -lah`, and double-check the permissions on the file.

Comment: run `pwd; for i in *.xml; do readlink -f  $i; done` and share the output ,also `pwd;ls gerhardloci.xml` , `pwd;rm gerhardloci.xml`

Comment: @jknotek there is no `.`(dot) as the prefix in the filename , so should not be hidden to ls

Comment: Getting "No such file or directory" just from running `ls -la` is not normal. Consider rebooting and running fsck

Comment: `find . -name "*gerhardloci.xml*" -exec stat '{}' \;`

Comment: read through `man ls` and try `--escape`, `--show-control-chars` or `--hide-control-chars`.

Comment: definitely a system problem. I still don't understand it. But I rebuilt the container and the problem seemed to be solved.

Comment: @Jeff : Do you see the file, when you do a `stat *` in the directory?